# FOSUserBundle with Symfony 3.0

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to get FOSUserBundle up and running after upgrading Symfony from version 2.6 to 3.0. On 2.6 I basically had a site, css and js we're handles by assetic, FOSUserBundle was up and running an I had configured SQLite via doctrine.

So before picking this project up again I did the upgrade because 2.6 was no longer supported.

Because I'm new to Symfony everything I did is more or less copied from the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html). FOSUserBundle is showing up as an enabled bundle in dev-mode. Alle my code is in */src/AppBundle*. I'm using the 2.0-dev version of FOSUserBundle (e770bfa to be precise).

Here's a part of my template:

```
<li>
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">
        {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
    </a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">
        {{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
    </a>
{% endif %}
</li>
```

At 2.6 I got

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.yml"
```

in my */src/AppBundle/config/routing.xml*. If I keep it this way I can't even load the site because of an Exception

```
"Unable to generate a URL for the named route "fos_user_security_login" as such route does not exist."
```

After putting it in */app/config/routing.yml* my site shows and the other routes defined in */src/AppBundle/config/routing.xml* work. So it was nothing wrong with this file.

When the site shows up the translation of the links is broken.

```
{{ 'layout.login'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

Shows up as "layout.login" instead aus Login as before with 2.6. And if I click the link to log in (the path is as expected */login*). Symfony tells me:

```
Unable to find template "AppBundle:Pages:login.html.twig".
```

I don't get why it's looking for it in the AppBundle folder? According to what I read it should look for it in the FOSUserBundle folder or in */app/Ressources/FOSUserBundle/...* which is where I put it to override the default template. I confirmed that this is still the way to override templates even with version 3.0.

I also tried to put the template in the *AppBulde/Pages/* folder. Then it finds the template but it's still not working.

I cleared the cache multiple times (this solved another problem with assetic).

It look for me as if I'm missing a significant part to get FOSUserBundle working. Any suggestions on what I might have overlooked?

Comment: periodically see routes that you have! php bin/console debug:router

Answer (score 3):

FOSUserBundle seems to be use 'xml' files for routing, and you have include an 'yml' file in your routing.xml:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.yml"
```

Comment: or try copy that file as *AppBundle/Routing/FOSUserBundle/all.xml*, and import in your *routing.xml* "@AppBundle/Routing/FOSUserBundle/all.xml"